# How to get the date of a specific day in a specific week

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I wanto to get the date of a specific day in a specific week, identified by the week number.

Here's an example:

Today it is Monday (03.10.2016) and it is the week with the number 58.
Now i want to get the date of e.g. Friday of this week.

I use Joda-Time within my android application.

Currently Iam creating a LocalDate.

```
    // This is the date of today
private LocalDate reportDate = new LocalDate();

// The number of the week is calculated here
int week = Weeks.weeksBetween(startDate.dayOfWeek().withMinimumValue().minusDays(1),
        reportDate.dayOfWeek().withMaximumValue().plusDays(1)).getWeeks();

switch(day_of_week) {
    case "Monday":
        // Get date of this day in current week
        break;
    case "Tuesday":
        // Get date of this day in current week
        break;
    // ...
```

Comment: I'm not clear how the week number affects the calculation. If the report date is 3rd Oct and day_of_week is Tuesday, presumably the answer would be the 4th Oct, regardless of what the week number is? Also do you care that in the locales the first day of the week isn't monday?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to achieve the days as desired,

```
    LocalDateTime yourDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    System.out.println(yourDate.getWeekOfWeekyear());
    int weekOfyear = yourDate.getWeekOfWeekyear();
    //Fetch Week Start Date for Given Week Number
    DateTime weekStartDate = new DateTime().withWeekOfWeekyear(weekOfyear);
    System.out.println(weekStartDate.toString());
    //Fetch Specific Days for given week
    DateTime wedDateTime = weekStartDate.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.WEDNESDAY);
```

I hope this answer your query.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding of your requirement I have implemented below code, just check if it helps you,

**First Import Calendar Package As Below**

```
import java.util.Calendar;
```

**Now Create below function**

```
public String getSpecificDate(int weekOfYear, int dayOfWeek)
{    

   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, weekOfYear);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);

    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);      // 0 to 11
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    String selectedDate = " " + day + "-" +  (month+1) + "-" + year;
    return selectedDate;
}

// I have passed getSpecificDate(41, 6) and get 7-10-2016 as output
```